# BufferedWriter prints only last line to the file?

Tags: append, filewriter, bufferedwriter

In the Code below I tried to write more textlines in a File, but it shows just the last line.

Maybe someone might help ?

Thanks

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
      writer.append("***");
      writer.append(aF);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        writer.append("***\r\n");
        writer.append("more text here\r\n");
        writer.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I might be wrong, but I've never seen it with `try {}`

**Edit**: this worked for me

Comment: the IDE choosed this.

Comment: woops my bad, I thought this was c#, but apparently it's java. Might be useful to specify what language you're working in next time. I'll try to make a little test project to see if I can find a solution

Comment: Yes sorry it is Java 8. The String aF, comes from a an Array. On a out.println(aF); it works, but not with writer(aF);.

Comment: this is also in my code,                      writer.newLine(); 
                                                          writer.flush();
                                                          writer.close();

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally clear the file before this code is executed?

Comment: no i can't see an clear, there is only one method with the writers. I try it now with a test code too.

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to help you any further then, because the code above worked for me. If it doesn't work for you, it must be something else interfering, like other code or something with your os. 
I'm sorry

Comment: this is where I parse the string from.        for(String as : content)  
                                                                  aF = as;

Comment: So the output would be that aF is equal to the last string in content?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nonetheless for the time and help.

Below is a Testcode which i tried, maybe we can find out how to add more lines.

```
public class FsIterateTest {
File f;
String[] fsl;
String path = "C:/";  
String ps;
File fp;
String ln;
String[] s;
List<String> contentAsList;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

 new FsIterateTest().hfsList();
}

private void hfsList() throws IOException {
  //System.out.println(ln);
  fp = new File("C://");
  fp.isDirectory();
  System.out.println(fp.isDirectory());
  s = fp.list();
  contentAsList = Arrays.asList(s);
  for(String fs : contentAsList){
   this.ln = fs;
  }hfsWrite(ln);
}

private void hfsWrite(String ln) throws IOException {
  System.out.println(ln);
  File nf = new File("C://db.txt");
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(nf);
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
  bw.newLine();
  bw.write(ln);
  bw.append("\r\n");
  bw.flush();
  bw.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry about, okay i will do it for other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it, thank you very much.

It was due a Problem in the for loop. The method which starts to give the the parameter with the string, must be in the loop closed with brackets.

I'm sorry for this little mistake.

```
for(String fs : contentAsList) {
 this.ln = fs;
 hfsWrite(ln);
}
```